# How to import table in different number of columns?

Tags: oracle, datapump

I'm using data pump export/import method in Oracle 11GR2

So, I have table A containing (ID, Name, Address, City, Phone) and I want to export it into table B (ID, Name, Address).

How can I import data from table A to table B that have different number of columns in table B???

It always gives me error ORA-39112 :(

Please help me guys..#newbie here

Here's my code:

```
expdp USERID="admin"@orcl DIRECTORY=dmpdir TABLES="A"."table_a"
      FILE=tb_a.dmp GRANTS=Y ROWS=Y LOG=exportTables.log

impdp USERID="admin"@target FULL=Y CONSTRAINTS=Y FILE=tb_a.dmp
      IGNORE=Y GRANTS=Y ROWS=Y COMMIT=Y LOG=importTables.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly this is about [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). If I were you I would import it into the same table ("table_a") as well and then move the data from this table to the desired one ("table_b") with a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: yes..Im doing data warehouse right now
but Im very confuse to import table in different number of columns :(
Can u teach me??

Comment: It seems to me that you need to import the table in a table with the same number of columns and then run a PL/SQL procedure that move/copy the data from the table (you fill after the import) to the table you want. But, in my opinion, you might need to use [Oracle Data Integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Data_Integrator) to reach your goal. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340872/what-is-oracle-data-integrator) for a good brief explanation.

Comment: Oracle Marketing thanks you for your suggestion.  You should have  mentioned that ODI is licensed separately from the database.

Comment: @APC Thank you for your comment)) I totally forgot to mention it, sometimes it matters.